# monkeyrunner command not found

Tags: android, linux, shell, monkeyrunner

I navigate to my tools dir

```
cd /home/username/android-sdks/tools
```

and run the

```
monkeyrunner somescrip
```

and it says

```
monkeyrunner: command not found
```

I have the android home path set, but still this doesn't works

the interesting thing is that when I type ls command I see the monekyrunner

```
dmtracedump   etc1tool         mksdcard           sqlite3
android            draw9patch    hierarchyviewer  monkeyrunner       traceview
ant                emulator      hprof-conv       NOTICE.txt         zipalign
apkbuilder         emulator-arm  layoutopt        proguard
ddms               emulator-x86  lib              source.properties
```

Comment: Welcome to the *nix world, where `.` isn't on your `$PATH`. ;-)

Comment: He probably doesn't want that anyway (at least not in this case) as creating `somescrip` in the tools directory might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `/home/username/android-sdks/tools` to the PATH, call `./monkeyrunner` from that directory or call `/home/username/android-sdks/tools/monkeyrunner` from the directory where `somescrip` is lcoated (the first is the correct solution)